# I am having trouble creating code that opens links and closes them after running a specific command

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to create a command that opens the links I printed out, runs a specific command, closes them and opens another one until the links run out.

I just don't know how.

A command that prints links:

[image: poop code]

A specific command that I would like to see run on each link.:

[image: poopier code]

Links example:

[image: shitstorm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First grab all the links and then driver.get(link). This way prevents stale elements and is generally the most stable.

```
links =[ link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("yourxpath")]
for link in links:
     driver.get(link)
     # proceed with your click action in a try except
```

Comment: Thanks everything works as it should, just don't know what to put in "except:" sry I am a beginner. code I use now: links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in chrome.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='raffle-name']/a[@href]")]
for link in links:
     chrome.get(link)
     try:
         time.sleep(2)
         Button.click()
        except:

Comment: Should grab the button in there as well and put an error message in the except.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm:

1. Open the browser and log in into site(manually or using python) or load browser's profile with logged in data.
2. Get page with all raffles. Get all links (don't forget about dynamically loaded links, google about scrolling with python, and wait for appearence of block with "That's all, no more!", then you can grab links)(implementing of ajax requests is a better way to get links without scrolling I guess, to https://scrap.tf/ajax/raffles/Paginate (f12->network)).
3. Load every link and press "Enter raffle" button. Don't forget to make delays between actions(site is blocking frequent entering raffle)
4. Profit.

I'm not a pro. Algorithm is not the best and my English too. It's just a food for thought. But I'm pretty sure it will work.

GL&HF